# Django, The current path, blog/, didn't match any of these

Tags: django

Please help with this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUs3z.png)

Comment: Please add your urls.py file. Because according to screenshot `admin` is specified only.

Comment: Did you register your app to `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py?

Comment: No need to show up your urls.py. cause the reason is clear. You didn't registered `blog` url in your urls.py, just `admin` is registered!

Answer (score 1):

First, Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to add codes to your question so that other users can have a background.

From what I see, there are two possibilities.
First, you have not added `blog` to the `INSTALLED_APPS` in the `settings.py`. To do that:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
]
```

second possible problem is that you haven't added `blog/` url to the list of urls. To do this, add the following to the `urls.py` file next to your `settings.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

Then, in the `blog` app create a file named `urls.py` and then add the following:

```
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.blog_view, name='blog_view'),
]
```